# How to disable displaying "New version of Jenkins (2.62) is available for download (changelog)"?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

seems jenkins is getting updated very frequently. I dont want to see those message where jenkins is popping with red button saying "N**ew version of Jenkins (2.62) is available for download (changelog)**".
any one know how to disable this feature in jenkins? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 30):

To manually disable it

```
Manage Jenkins => Configure System => Administrative monitors configuration
```

UnCheck "Jenkins Update Notification" and apply

Comment: It would be nice to be able to configure to just show updates of LTS versions. Or do this automatically if an LTS version is installed.